# Adding Non Activity Classes to Dagger 2 Graph Android

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to use Dagger 2.0 outside of the limited examples I've seen. Let's take an example reading application. In this reading app, there is a library of a user's stories and the ability to Log in. The classes of interest for the purpose of this example are:

`MainApplication.java` - extends Application

`LibraryManager.java` - Manager which is responsible for adding/removing stories in the user's library. This is called from the `MainApplication`

`AccountManager.java` - Manager which is responsible for saving all a user's login information. It can be called from the LibraryManager

I'm still trying to wrap my head around what Components and Modules I should be creating. Here's what I can gather so far:

Create a `HelperModule` that provides an `AccountManager` and `LibraryManager` instance:

```
@Module
public class HelperModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AccountManager provideAccountManager() {
        return new AccountManager();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LibraryManager provideLibraryManager() {
        return new LibraryManager();
    }

}
```

Create a `MainApplicationComponent` that lists the `HelperModule` in its list of modules:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, HelperModule.class})
public interface MainApplicationComponent {
    MainApplication injectApplication(MainApplication application);
}
```

Include `@Injects LibraryManager libraryManager` in the `MainApplication` and inject the application into the graph. Finally it queries the injected `LibraryManager` for the number of stories in the library:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Inject LibraryManager libraryManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = DaggerMainApplicationComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .helperModule(new HelperModule())
                .build();
        component.injectApplication(this);

        // Now that we have an injected LibraryManager instance, use it
        libraryManager.getLibrary();
    }
}
```

Inject the `AccountManager` into the `LibraryManager`

```
public class LibraryManager {
    @Inject AccountManager accountManager;

    public int getNumStoriesInLibrary() {
        String username = accountManager.getLoggedInUserName();
        ...
    }
}
```

However the problem is that the `AccountManager` is null when I try to use it in the `LibraryManager` and I don't understand why or how to solve the problem. I'm thinking that it's because the `MainApplication` that was injected into the graph doesn't use the AccountManager directly, but then do I need to inject the `LibraryManager` into the graph some how?

Comment: Incidentally, as it has no parameters, you don't need to include the HelperModule in your Component builder.

Comment: @steffandroid that's what I was thinking as well, but then why isn't the AccountManager in the LibraryManager getting initialized?

Answer (score 7):

modify your classes as follow and it would work:

your POJO:

```
public class LibraryManager {
    @Inject AccountManager accountManager;

    public LibraryManager(){
        MainApplication.getComponent().inject(this);
    }

    public int getNumStoriesInLibrary() {
        String username = accountManager.getLoggedInUserName();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

your component Interface:

```
 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, HelperModule.class})
    public interface MainApplicationComponent {
        void inject(MainApplication application);
        void inject(LibraryManager lm);
    }
 }
```

your application Class :

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    private static MainApplicationComponent component;

    @Inject LibraryManager libraryManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = DaggerMainApplicationComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .helperModule(new HelperModule())
                .build();
        component.injectApplication(this);

        // Now that we have an injected LibraryManager instance, use it
        libraryManager.getLibrary();
    }

    public static MainApplicationComponent getComponent(){return component;}


}
```

In fact, you need to do the same for all of your dependent classes, basically you have access to the application class in all Activity sub-classes so making get component as an static method is none-less. but for POJO u need to catch the component somehow. there are a lot of way to implement. this is just an illustration to give u the idea how it works.
now you can destroy the mars :)

Comment: This is how we do it and it has been working so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can satisfy dependency directly in provide method:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
LibraryManager provideLibraryManager(AccountManager accountManager) {
    return new LibraryManager(accountManager);
}
```

Or use constructor injection (remove `provideLibraryManager()` method from `HelperModule`):

```java
@Signleton
public class LibraryManager {
    private final AccountManager accountManager;

    @Inject
    public LibraryManager(AccountManager accountManager) {
      this.accountManager = accountManager
    }

    public int getNumStoriesInLibrary() {
        String username = accountManager.getLoggedInUserName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Objects created with constructor injection are provided automatically.

If you have a lot of parameters in `LibraryManager` you can use method injection for setters in addition to constructor injection:

```
@Singleton
public class LibraryManager {
    private final AccountManager accountManager;
    private SomeManager someManager;

    @Inject
    public LibraryManager(AccountManager accountManager) {
      this.accountManager = accountManager
    }

    @Inject
    public setSomeManager(SomeManager someManager) {
       this.someManager = someManager
    }

    public int getNumStoriesInLibrary() {
        String username = accountManager.getLoggedInUserName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Method injection is performed after object is instantiated. However, this use case of method injection is not valid, try to prefer constructor or field injection.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really want constructor injection because of how large the constructor would be. In my actual app there are >10 managers/db adapters/helper classes/etc. that the LibraryActivity deals with and putting them all in the constructor would become unruly.

Comment: If you want to provide `LibraryManager` as dependency, you need either use constructor injection or create object manually and satisfy all dependencies in corresponding provide method in module. Or you can use method injection as setters for other >10 parameters but it's not valid use case actually. I can update my answer with method injection.

Comment: What do you mean 'create object manually and satisfy all dependencies in corresponding provide method in module'? I am doing that already aren't I but having two @Provides methods, one for LibraryManager and one for AccountManager? Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: In provide method you cannot inject `AccountManager` to `LibraryManager`. Because component does not exist yet. What I mean is if  constructor injection does not fit for you, you can create libraryManager with `new LibraryManager`, then set dependencies with setters e.g. `libraryManager.setAccountManager(accountManager)` and return in as dependency. But thats very dirty. Actual injection won't happen until you call `component.inject(libraryManager)` (field injection) or perform constructor injection or constructor+method injection. I'll update answer with method injection to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. The method injection method looks like it would work. What do you mean by 'this use case of method injection is not valid'?

Comment: See Jake Wharton's talk about Dagger 2: https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-devoxx-2014?slide=145 and https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-devoxx-2014?slide=147.

Comment: If you want to avoid excessive constructors, use the [builder pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternBuilder/article.html).

Comment: @KirillBoyarshinov it still feels like there's something missing then if I don't want constructor injection and method injection is not valid. It seems like this is a pretty common use case.

Comment: @odiggity Do you need to inject `LibraryManager` somewhere else or it is used only in application subclass?

Comment: @steffandroid that's not what I want either, I'm looking for a way for Dagger to initialize the dependencies as singletons at the beginning. Right now all of the dependencies (managers, adapters, helpers) are singletons or static classes so if you want to use the library manager you don't need to worry about initializing all it's dependencies.

Comment: @KirillBoyarshinov yep the LibraryManager is used all over the app, currently it is a singleton. That's why I want to use Dagger so it doesn't have to be a singleton and I can mock it out easier in unit testing.

Comment: @odiggity so I guess no options left. Either constructor injection or constructor+method. By the way, maybe you need to split library manager to separate classes because having a class with 10+ constructor parameters is not good design. Splitting will allow to successfully use constructor injection without invalid method injection.

Comment: @KirillBoyarshinov I came up with a different solution and posted it as an answer. Lmk what you think. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with a pretty good solution. Instead of trying to inject the `AccountManager` into the `LibraryManager`, I'm providing the `AccountManager` in the `MainApplicationComponent` and accessing from the `LibraryManager` that way.

MainApplicationComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, HelperModule.class})
public interface MainApplicationComponent {
    MainApplication injectApplication(MainApplication application);

    // Provide the managers here so all classes that have a pointer to the MainApplicationComponent can access them.
    // This avoids having to pass each manager to the constructor of all classes that need them
    AccountManager accountManager();
    ArchiveManager archiveManager();
}
```

Using the sample Android App for inspiration (https://github.com/gk5885/dagger-android-sample) I've created a HasComponent interface:

```
public interface HasComponent<C> {
    C getComponent();
}
```

and made the MainApplication implement the interface. Also when creating the HelperModule you'll notice it passes this so the module can access the component:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements HasComponent<MainApplicationComponent>{

    MainApplicationComponent mainApplicationComponent;

    @Override
    public MainApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return mainApplicationComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = DaggerMainApplicationComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .helperModule(new HelperModule(this))
                .build();
        component.injectApplication(this);

        // Now that we have an injected LibraryManager instance, use it
        mainApplicationComponent.libraryManager().getLibrary();
    }
}
```

The LibraryManager is changed so it takes the HasComponent in as a parameter in the constructor:

```
public class LibraryManager {

    AccountManager accountManager;
    public ArchiveManager(HasComponent<MainApplicationComponent> hasComponent) {
        accountManager = hasComponent.getComponent().accountManager();
    }
    ...
}
```

and finally in the HelperModule we just pass the implementation of `HasComponent<MainApplicationComponent>` to the LibraryManager's constructor:

```
@Module
public class HelperModule {

private HasComponent<WattpadComponent> hasComponent;

public HelperModule(HasComponent<WattpadComponent> hasComponent) {
    this.hasComponent = hasComponent;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
AccountManager provideAccountManager() {
    return new AccountManager(hasComponent);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ArchiveManager provideLibraryManager() {
    return new LibraryManager(hasComponent);
}

}
```

This should also make it really easy for unit testing. If I am unit testing the `LibraryManager` and want to mock out the `AccountManager` I can simply create a `TestMainApplicationComponent` that extends MainApplicationComponent and includes a `TestHelperModule` in it's list of modules which will provide a mocked `AccountManager` and pass the `TestMainApplicationComponent` to the `LibraryManager`'s constructor.

I'm new to Dagger so I might be missing something but I've tried out everything but the unit testing and it seems to be working so far. Will post a GitHub link shortly with unit testing examples for those interested.

Thanks to @Kirill's answer for a better understanding of how the Components instantiate the objects.

Comment: Well, looks unusual. Is this works for you? But what if cyclic dependency happens? As far as I see it can break everything, cause components rely on modules in creating dependencies. But you've turned it backwards: dependencies rely on component to create themselves. What if `AccountManager` request `LibraryManager` and vice versa?